# URL being appended with a string at the end

Tags: dns, subdomain

I registered a new domain and then I pointed it to my nameservers.  Whenever I type it into my browser it comes back "DNS address cannot be found".  I flushed the DNS then Tested it on "http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/" it comes back "Failed to find name servers of example-domain.com/IN"

Why is it appending "/IN" on to the end of my URL?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a URL, it's a domain name. And the `IN` is for the DNS class in question. `IN` is for "internet". There is also `CH` for ChaosNet and `HS` for Hesiod. The latter two are, to put it mildly, rather rare these days.